# why a anchor with empty text showing length 3

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove a anchor tag if the anchor tag have no value. but when i check its showing 3. So need to add <4 for condition but I want it with out any length like === 0 or any way

```html
<a href="https://www.example.com/abc/xyz"> 

</a>
```

```
if( !$(this).text() ) {
      $(this).remove();
}
```

Second method

```
if( $(this).text().length === 0 ) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Comment: White-space counts as text, you've got two line breaks and, maybe, a space in there.

Answer (score 1):

`3` is the length of the white spaces in the anchor, so use `String::trim()` to check whether the anchor's text is empty:

```js
const remove = () => {
  
  const $anchor = $('a');
  
  if(!$anchor.text().trim()){
    console.log('removing the anchor!');
    $anchor.remove();
  }

  console.log('anchors on the page:', $('a').length);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.googloe.com/"> 

</a>

<button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
```